# Long in C# won't fit the same value as Long in Java

Tags: c#, java, long-integer

```
static long[] Mask1=
{
        0xFF, 0xFF00, 0xFF0000, 0xFF000000, 
        0xFF00000000, 0xFF0000000000, 0xFF000000000000, 0xFF00000000000000
};

static long[] Mask2 =
{
        0x101010101010101, 0x202020202020202, 0x404040404040404, 0x808080808080808,
        0x1010101010101010, 0x2020202020202020, 0x4040404040404040, 0x8080808080808080
};
```

In Java, I can put these values into long[] just fine.

But in C#, I get that they cannot be 'convert to a long'.

I can only use a ulong in C#, but why when Java long and C# long have the same capacity? –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 no?
Is there an extra specifier I need for the masks?

Specifically my errors are:

```
"Constant value `18374686479671623680' cannot be converted to a `long'"

Constant value `9259542123273814144' cannot be converted to a `long'
```

Comment: Java `long`s are signed. Not sure what's going on in C#.

Comment: 9259542123273814144>9223372036854775807 I don't understand how do you fit in in long in java or c#. The later number is the max value for long in both languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long.MaxValue = 9223372036854775807
your value 1  = 18374686479671623680
your value 2  = 9259542123273814144
```

Your values are bigger than the signed long can hold. This is why you have to use unsigned.

Comment: Right, but why is Java taking them and not complaining when it normally does? Or so I thought.

Comment: Use 'unchecked' - this will give you the same result as Java.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an 'unchecked' cast in C# for the out-of-range values:

```
static long[] Mask1 = {0xFF, 0xFF00, 0xFF0000, 0xFF000000, 0xFF00000000, 0xFF0000000000, 0xFF000000000000, unchecked((long)0xFF00000000000000)};

static long[] Mask2 = {0x101010101010101, 0x202020202020202, 0x404040404040404, 0x808080808080808, 0x1010101010101010, 0x2020202020202020, 0x4040404040404040, unchecked((long)0x8080808080808080)};
```